# Loading files based on pattern matching in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have 31 inputs files with named from `date=2018-01-01` till `date=2018-01-31`.

I am able to load all these files into an rdd this way:

```
val input = sc.textFile("hdfs://user/cloudera/date=*")
```

But what if I want to load the files for only 1 week? (files from date=2018-01-15 to date=2018-01-22).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify your files individually to `textFile` by joining them with `,`:

```
val files = (15 to 22).map(
  day => "hdfs://user/cloudera/date=2018-01-" + "%02d".format(day)
).mkString(",")
```

which produces:

```
hdfs://user/cloudera/date=2018-01-15,hdfs://user/cloudera/date=2018-01-16,hdfs://user/cloudera/date=2018-01-17,hdfs://user/cloudera/date=2018-01-18,hdfs://user/cloudera/date=2018-01-19,hdfs://user/cloudera/date=2018-01-20,hdfs://user/cloudera/date=2018-01-21,hdfs://user/cloudera/date=2018-01-22
```

and you can call it this way:

```
val input = sc.textFile(files)
```

Notice the formatting (`"%02d".format(day)`) of the day in order to add the leading 0 to days between 1 and 9.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell me what is the significance of mkString(",")? If I make the input as String I am not able to register it as temp table 'input.registerTempTable("tmp")'.

Comment: `mkString(",")` joins a sequence into a String. Your second point should probably be another question as it's not linked to the original question and we might require a bit more details.

Comment: @XavierGuihot what happen if the path not available in file system. It gives Path does not exist . how to add regex which need to read valid files in the path. ignore if files not available

Answer (score 2):

Filtering by listing specific files to load works, but why not go one step further with `DataFrameReader` so Spark SQL can be used to filter out `date` as a proper column? It probably doesn't matter much in your use case with CSV files (that tend to be small) and you are going to use RDDs, but learning newer Spark APIs might be beneficial in future. For Spark 2.0+ with https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

```
  val df = spark
    .read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", "true") // Use first line of all files as header
    .option("inferSchema", "true") // Automatically infer data types
    .option("basePath", "hdfs://user/cloudera/") // see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery
    .load("hdfs://user/cloudera/*")

  val rdd = df
    .filter($"date" >= "2018-01-01" && $"date" <= "2018-01-31")
    .rdd
```

This approach uses newer API to load data, Spark SQL to filter out needed Hive partitions and relies on Spark Catalyst to figure out only necessary files to load (from your `filter`). May become more useful when you switch to larger amounts of data and more advanced file formats like Parquet.

Simplified demo in spark-shell (Spark 2.0.2):

1) Prepare CSV files

```
% cat ~/testdata/date=2018-01-03/test1
A,B,C
21,22,23
24,25,26
% cat ~/testdata/date=2018-01-02/test1
A,B,C
11,12,13
14,15,16
% cat ~/testdata/date=2018-01-01/test1
A,B,C
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

2) Run in spark-shell

```
scala> val df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("basePath", "/Users/igork/testdata/").load("/Users/igork/testdata/*")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: int, B: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- A: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- B: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- C: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)


scala> val rdd = df.filter($"date" >= "2018-01-01" && $"date" <= "2018-01-02").rdd
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = MapPartitionsRDD[25] at rdd at <console>:25

scala> rdd.collect().foreach(println)
[11,12,13,2018-01-02]
[14,15,16,2018-01-02]
[1,2,3,2018-01-01]
[4,5,6,2018-01-01]
```

Note how RDD (and DataFrame) now contain `date` as a string column with value taken from the path. This is covered in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#partition-discovery

Comment: Nice. Only thing is that you need the partition appoach which not all wil do.

Comment: better to actually use the Hive partition style of 'directory' naming when partitioning data with Spark - this allows Catalyst to figure out automatically what files to load based on `filter()`

Comment: So, the following. With large files I assume we would not do this. Interesting is that we use LINUX scripting with IMPALA SQL for many things and not SPARK.  I get the impression this is evolutionary and that most things can be done in SPARK as well know that have UNIX scripting. However, ... Also, we are using KUDU, so I wonder how well the Catalyst works. I am trying to see how Catalyst works under the hood. The book High Performance Spark is thin on that I note.

Comment: So, in elation to your filter, if one writes a complicated query against a tempview, how will Catalyst partition? I hear it has 200 partitions standardly. I am going to explain with an example.

Comment: Not every query can benefit from it, but some will. Try to print plan for the example here: `df.filter($"date" >= "2018-01-01" && $"date" <= "2018-01-02").explain(true)` . AFAIK for Spark 2.0.2 interesting parts are around `FileSourceStrategy` https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/dccd8c7549390a6f46272182052dcf17e5e51319/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileSourceStrategy.scala#L44 , it will read only the files matching partitions specified - you should see part of it reflected in plan print out.

Comment: Impala is a totally different thing, would be very surprised if it cannot handle partitioned Hive tables efficiently though, e.g. see https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_partitioning.html `A query that includes a WHERE condition such as YEAR=1966, YEAR IN (1989,1999), or YEAR BETWEEN 1984 AND 1989 can examine only the data files from the appropriate directory or directories, greatly reducing the amount of data to read and test.`

Comment: Impala can do that, that is not an issue

Comment: I'm not claiming that I can explain in general case how/when exactly Spark Catalyst or Impala optimizer can definitely use that info for some positive performance impact. Printing plan for Spark should help. But if you don't use Hive partitions for Spark - it will definitely not be able to optimize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176615/discussion-between-igork-and-thebluephantom).

Comment: What timezone you in? Need to work, so interesting discussion to continue. So for KUDU ...?